# Kotlin app configuration kafka consumer and produser with avro has failed

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-kafka, yaml

При попытке сконфигурировать кафку через application.yaml получаю ошибки при конфигурации consumer и producer вместе с авро сериализатором и дисериализатором. Приложение написано на kotlin. application.yaml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: test
  cloud:
    consul:
      enabled: false
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: dest
          group: group
          consumer:
            concurrency: 12
            instanceCount: 2
            partitioned: true
            useNativeDecoding: true
        output:
          destination: dest
          group: grout
          producer:
            partitionKeyExpression: headers['header']
            partitionCount: 24
            headerMode: headers
            useNativeEncoding: true
      kafka:
        bindings:
          input:
            consumer:
              startOffset: latest
              resetOffsets: true
              configuration:
                client.id: test
                key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
                value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
                schema.registry.url: urls..
          output:
            producer:
              configuration:
                client.id: test
                key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
                value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
                schema.registry.url: urls..
        binder:
          brokers: brokers..
          configuration:
            sasl.mechanism: PLAIN
            security.protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
            sasl.jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="admin" password="admin";
          required-acks: -1
          replication-factor: 3
```

Ошибки:

```
Producer

    org.apache.

kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:457)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:289)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.createKafkaProducer(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.createProducer(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:305)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.lambda$createProducerMessageHandler$0(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:287)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.lambda$getPartitionsForTopic$2(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:410)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:164)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.getPartitionsForTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:405)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createProducerMessageHandler(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:284)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createProducerMessageHandler(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:132)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:184)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:90)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:151)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.lambda$rescheduleProducerBinding$2(BindingService.java:290)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Could not instantiate class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:310)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:302)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:370)
        ... 22 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor58.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:306)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/common/Configurable
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerDe.<init>(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDe.java:46)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.<init>(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:37)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.<init>(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:32)
        ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Для consumer аналогичная, только с дисериализатором.

Зависимости в грэдле:

```
implementation ("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka:2.1.1.RELEASE")
implementation ("io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client:4.1.1")
implementation ("io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:4.1.1")
implementation ("org.apache.avro:avro-compiler:1.8.2")
```

С чем может быть связано?

Answer (score 0):

Я читал, что для работы с авро-спецификациями у confluent используется реестр-сервис.

Сам использую protobuf.

Comment: К сожалению перейти на какой то другой "протокол" не имеется возможности.

Comment: так реестр-сервис доступен?

Comment: если вопрос про schema.registry.url, то да

Comment: может в схеме какие-то аномалии в округе 58-го ...

Comment: ... кто-то убрал поле, или добавил поле с необычным типом